postgres auto vacuum & analyze not updating until manually ran?
I have a postgres table that looks like this:
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batch_update_data (
 id TEXT DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()::TEXT
, account_id TEXT
, processed boolean
...
);

it has an index that looks like this:
CREATE INDEX batch_update_data__processed_false_idx ON batch_update_data(processed) WHERE processed = FALSE;
when ever I batch load data into that table, I run a query like this right after:
SELECT
 id,
...
FROM
  batch_update_data
WHERE
  processed = false
LIMIT
  10

but this doesn't hit an index until I run this:
VACUUM ANALYZE public.batch_update_data;
I can see vacuum running during the batch load in the logs so why doesn't it hit an index until I manually run it?
my current auto vacuum settings are the following:
"autovacuum"    "on"
"autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor"   "0.1"
"autovacuum_analyze_threshold"  "50"
"autovacuum_freeze_max_age" "200000000"
"autovacuum_max_workers"    "3"
"autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age"   "400000000"
"autovacuum_naptime"    "60"
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay"  "2"
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit"  "-1"
"autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor"    "0.2"
"autovacuum_vacuum_threshold"   "50"
"autovacuum_work_mem"   "-1"
"log_autovacuum_min_duration"   "0"

----- EDIT ----
here is the explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) output on the query.. I'm using pg11 so I don't think the settings is an option?
"Limit  (cost=0.00..2.49 rows=10 width=100) (actual time=3.050..3.056 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, account_id, customer_id, account_open_date, account_close_date, sec_pool_id, product_code, latest_card_last_4, card_art, card_bank, expiration_date"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11"
"  ->  Seq Scan on public.batch_update_data  (cost=0.00..864045.52 rows=3474519 width=100) (actual time=3.048..3.051 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, account_id, customer_id, account_open_date, account_close_date, sec_pool_id, product_code, latest_card_last_4, card_art, card_bank, expiration_date"
"        Filter: (NOT batch_update_data.processed)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 605"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11"
"Planning Time: 3.282 ms"
"Execution Time: 3.095 ms"


Could you share the query plan? Please use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) and post it in plain text as an update of your question. By the way, booleans are pretty bad for indexing, it's just true/false/null. In your case 100% of the index. Why don't you store a uuid as a uuid? That's twice as fast as text because it takes half the space.

made an edit with it above!

Either you don't run the bulk load in a single transaction, so that autovacuum or autoanalyze kick in in the middle of loading data (and doesn't have statistics for your later additions), or you don't wait long enough after the bulk load to give autoanalyze time to do its job.
Both problems would be fixed by running an explicit ANALYZE on the table right after the bulk load is done. That is the best practice, particularly if you intend to run queries right after the bulk load.

we're using COPY to do this from STDIN... does that not do a bulk load?

@lightweight Yes, COPY is a bulk load. After this COPY statement, most likely you need to run ANALYZE. But first improve the table, index and query, see my other response.

Yes, a COPY would do a bulk load in a single transaction. You need an explicit ANALYZE.

It's not lightning fast, but 3 milliseconds isn't slow either. Run ANALYZE after the batch import. A limit without an order by is usually not a good idea. Create an index on the order by column (id or account_id) and use the column processed in the where condition:
CREATE INDEX batch_update_data_processed_false_idx ON batch_update_data(id) WHERE processed = FALSE;

And your new query:
SELECT
 id,
...
FROM
  batch_update_data
WHERE
  processed = false
ORDER BY id ASC -- sorting on id, that's in the index
LIMIT
  10;

And of course you use a UUID for the id column, not text:
ALTER TABLE batch_update_data
    ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT (gen_random_uuid());

ALTER TABLE batch_update_data
    ALTER COLUMN id TYPE uuid USING(CAST(id AS UUID));


The statistic collector generally doesn't get a report about new rows until the transaction commits (or rollsback).  So until the bulk load commits, autovac is unlikely to process the table as it doesn't know about the new rows yet.  And once it does commit, it still will take a while because it only looks once every autovacuum_naptime, and it might have other stuff to do before it gets to this particular table.
Even if it did happen to analyze the table during the bulk load, it doesn't gather statistics on uncommitted rows (unless the ANALYZE is in the same uncommitted transaction as the rows are, which obviously autovacuum is not), so that stats wouldn't be useful once the load is done.
In short, if you want your bulk upload to be reflected in the stats at a time certain, then do a manual ANALYZE.
